# High r square but strong pattern in residuals

Tags: plotting, fitting

I analyze the development of the total number of users over time. It is obvious that a linear regression fits the data. The r squared is then also 0.9961.

Now the problem: a plot of the residuals shows the presence of a pattern. This should not be the case if the model would be correct.

Does anyone have experience how to solve this issue? I tried time series model fit, which gave me a random walk model (ARIMA 0,1,0) but I am not able to find out the coefficients of this model, which is exactly what I need.

Thanks.

Comment: The chances of getting a useful response go up considerably if you add the code you used (in copy-pastable form, so others can experiment with modifications).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/).  But it would still need more details given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As JimB said, it's not a MMA question. Cross Validated talks about residual indexing, but if you don't think your model is correct, then ad hoc modeling - modeling the residuals and adding that to your original model, isn't the way to go.

Since you noticed a pattern in the time series, where do you think it came from? Is it different on weekends or, say, Fridays? Is there autocorrelation? Go play with the data!